# Angular js set default tab with ng-repeat in array object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, tabs

I want to show last object of each tab in default tab. Now my interface is like this: `tab[0]` last object is `{"id": 8, "status": 1}`, `tab[1]` last object is `{"id": 8, "status": 1}` but it is wrong. I want it to look like this: `tab[0]` last object is `{"id": 5, "status": 0}`, tab[1]`last object is`{"id": 8, "status": 1}`.

Image of my wrong interface: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhvKX.png

My json data like this:

```
[
  {
    "tab":[
            [
              {"id": 1, "status": 1},
              {"id": 2, "status": 1},
              {"id": 3, "status": 1},
            ],
            [
              {"id": 4, "status": 1},
            ],
            [
              {"id": 5, "status": 0}
            ]
          ]
  },
  {
    "tab":[
            [
              {"id": 6, "status": 1},
              { "id": 7, "status": 1},  
            ],
            [
              {"id": 8, "status": 1}
            ]
          ]
  },
];
```

My js:

```
for(let i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < $scope.data[i].tab.length; j++) { 
        $scope.selecttab = $scope.data[i].tab[j];
    }
}

$scope.getTab = function(obj) {
    $scope.selecttab = obj;
};
```

My html

```
<div ng-repeat="obj in data">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li ng-class="{ active: selecttab == obj1 }" ng-repeat="obj1 in obj.tab track by $index">
            <a href ng-click="getTab(obj1)">{{ $index }}</a>
        </li>
     </ul>
     <div class="tab-content" ng-repeat="obj1 in selecttab">
         ID: {{obj1.id}}<br>
         Status : {{obj1.status}}
     </div>
</div>
```

Can someone please help in identifying what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to correct your last tab selection logic.

Since `selectedTab` is specific to each node in your data array, I parsed the array and added a `selectedTab` property to each data node which holds its first.

**Working fiddle**

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [
    {
      "tab": [
        [{ "id": 1, "status": 1 }, { "id": 2, "status": 1 }, { "id": 3, "status": 1 }],
        [{ "id": 4, "status": 1 }],
        [{ "id": 5, "status": 0 }]
      ]
    },
    {
      "tab": [
        [{ "id": 6, "status": 1 }, { "id": 7, "status": 1 }],
        [{ "id": 8, "status": 1 }]
      ]
    },
  ];
  for (let i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++) {
    $scope.data[i].selectedTab = $scope.data[i].tab[$scope.data[i].tab.length - 1];
  }

  $scope.setSelectedTab = function (node, tab) {
    tab.selectedTab = node;
  };
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="obj in data">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li ng-class="{ active: obj1[0] && obj.selectedTab == obj1 }" ng-repeat="obj1 in obj.tab track by $index">
        <a href ng-click="setSelectedTab(obj1, obj)">{{ $index }} </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" ng-repeat="tab in obj.selectedTab track by $index">
      ID: {{tab.id}}<br>
      Status : {{tab.status}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but when i click on other tabs it doesn't show data

Comment: And i also have a problem. When I change tab in tab[0], data in tab[1] changes the same as tab[0]. How can I change tab[0] but tab[1] stay the same? pls help me

Comment: tkanks for reply, in your code just show 1 object, but it have 3 object. Example: tab[0][0] have 3 object `{ "id": 1, "status": 1 }, { "id": 2, "status": 1 }, { "id": 3, "status": 1 }`, but it just show 1 object `{ "id": 1, "status": 1 }`. pls help me

Comment: So your `selecttab` will be an attau, not just an object. Is that correct? If yes you wont be able to display `obj.selectedTab.id` or `obj.selectedTab.status` since its an array. Please confirm

Comment: yes. I want to show it like that [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnBB0.png.